# How to echo PHP after comment form submit?

Tags: comment-form

How can I echo PHP after a comment form submit?

I have tried this but no luck:

```
$args = array(
    'logged_in_as'         => '',
    'comment_notes_before' => '',
    'comment_notes_after'  => '',
    'name_submit'          => 'thesubmit',
    'id_form'              => 'commentform',
    'id_submit'            => 'submit',
    'title_reply'          => __( "", ET_DOMAIN),
    'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', ET_DOMAIN),
    'cancel_reply_link'    => __( 'Cancel reply',ET_DOMAIN ),
    'label_submit'         => __( 'continue', ET_DOMAIN ),
);

comment_form( $args, $post>ID ); 

if ( isset( $_POST['thesubmit'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'buzz', 1 ); 
}
```

Comment: first, `$post->ID` instead of `$post>ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Native comment form is not posting to the page itself, but away to a special `wp-comment-post.php` endpoint.

That endpoint processes the form submission, then redirects *back* to the page (which rebuilds with submitted comment if necessary). If you want to echo data at the page at the end of this process you would need to somehow keep track of this.

On top of my head you could hook into `comment_post_redirect` filter and add a GET query with data or something like that.